# How to create a MotionEvent with a specific controller axis value?

Tags: android, motionevent

I am trying to remapping some incorrect axis values from PS4 controller when connecting via bluetooth. The right analog of PS4 controller return axis values of `MotionEvent.AXIS_Z` and `MotionEvent.AXIS_RZ` when the correct ones must be `MotionEvent.AXIS_RX` and `MotionEvent.AXIS_RY`.

I thought that I should write an IME, intercept the motion event and replace the incorrect values by correct values, but how to replace it, I haven't figured out.
My sample code:

```
public class PS4RemapperKeyboard extends InputMethodService {
    private static final String TAG = PS4RemapperKeyboard.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float zAxis = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RX);
        float rzAxis = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RY);

        MotionEvent newEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("z = %.2f, rz = %.2f", zAxis, rzAxis));

        if (zAxis > 0.3 || rzAxis > 0.3) {
            // How to replace rx and ry axis values by z and rz axis values???
        }

        return super.onGenericMotionEvent(newEvent);
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me how to do it properly? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can do it via https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.PointerCoords#setAxisValue(int,%20float)

So you need to call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getPointerCoords(int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords) to acquire PointerCoords, the first parameter is 0, and then call setAxisValue on it

Answer (score 0):

do you manage to do what you wanted?
Probably the easiest way is to change keylayout .kt files, but i want to make something similar, and have some problems. I want to set values on one of the axis programmatically when i press another button. There is method in MotionEvent.pointercoords "setAxisValue" but i can't properly use it, because getAxisValue always return 0.0 for me. Maybe You have some ideas how to do it? Moreover i want to do it from service, at this moment i can switch any button to any keyCode i want or even do some other actions when key is pressed or released.

Comment: No, I have given up on this. If I remember correctly, editing kt files require root permission, but I want a solution without root.